# Time interval ExitSplash popup

Tags: jquery, timer

I like to display a javascript ExitSplash popup "A" for the first 5 minutes, and ExitSplash popup "B" for after 5 minutes. Not sure how to use "setTimeout()" for B.

```
<script language="javascript">
var exitsplashalertmessage = '*****';
var exitsplashmessage = '******';
var exitsplashpage = 'http://www.domain.com/';
</script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/exitsplash.php"></script>
```

Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

setting a **delay** for setTimeout():

```
var timeoutDur = 300000;
setTimeout(function(){
  ...
}, timeoutDur);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, so that popup **`B`** becomes active after five minutes of popup **`A`** being active.

```
var duration = 5*60*1000;
setTimeout( function() {

   //POPUP A STUFF HERE

   setTimeout( function(){

       //POPUP B STUFF HERE

   }, duration);

}, duration);
```

Comment: Sorry for my minimal knowledge.
But how should I put it in?

    var duration = 5*60*1000;
    setTimeout( function() {

    //POPUP A STUFF HERE
    var exitsplashalertmessage = 'A';
    var exitsplashmessage = 'AA';
    var exitsplashpage = 'pageA';
   
 setTimeout( function(){
       //POPUP B STUFF HERE
    var exitsplashalertmessage = 'BBBB';
    var exitsplashmessage = 'BBBBB';
    var exitsplashpage = 'PageB';

    }, duration);
    }, duration);

    </script>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/exitsplash.php"></script>